# qt creator и android sdk

Tags: qt, android-sdk, qtcreator

Пытаюсь собрать все необходимое для написания приложений под anroid через qt creator, жалуется на android sdk, мол установлены не все необходимые пакеты(всплывающее окно в управлении проектами,где нужно указывать путь к ndk,jdk и sdk.Предлагает обновить эти самые пакеты,но по кнопке "да" ничего не происходит).Соответственно,проекты не собираются,снова жалуется на sdk.Зашел в андроид студию,через sdk manager накачал туеву кучу хрен пойми чего,толку ноль.Какие такие пакеты ему надо?Еще нагуглил,что нужно папку tools со старой версии sdk закинуть, не помогло.

Comment: Вы, вот это читали: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html? И очень советую использовать рекомендуемую версию NDK, не новее

Comment: Конечно читал,NDK 10, jdk 8 , из sdk в студии удалил NDK(оно там 17-ое),даже tools заменил,все впустую.Насчет всего под разделом Configuring Your Development Host - насколько я понял,через GUI у меня это и так сделано

Comment: Ну,у меня стоит галочка напротив google usb driver в sdk manager,я так понял это и есть драйвер extras.Мб еще какие-то галочки проставить надо?Хотя вроде и так почти все загрузил

Comment: драйвер нужен для отладки на железке, а вам как я понимаю надо в sdk manager поставить галочку против требуемой версии и нажать кнопку обновить, к сожалению к меня сейчас нет этого под рукой. Из qt creator это не пойдёт, да. Можно картинку из QtCreator tools/options, где ругается...

Comment: https://ibb.co/dYQb7z
https://ibb.co/bxmSEe
https://ibb.co/bQdk0K
https://ibb.co/hUqb7z

Comment: Еще вот это заметил,при том кнопка штатного sdk ниже не работает https://ibb.co/gALanz

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен,в чем именно была проблема,но переустановка android studio исправила ошибку.Могу лишь заметить,что :
1)После удаления sdk у меня все равно осталась папка android studio с одной вложенной папкой и каким-то файлом, а стояла студия до этого в папке android studio1 (оно так ставилось автоматически из-за занятого имени),что очень странно-я в жизни студию до того не ставил.Удалил эту папку и поставил студию как надо
2)При установке студии появились шаги,которых я не помню,возможно это связанно с тем,что при первой установке я не выбирал галочку "import settings from previous version"(вроде бы так называлась),а ставил ее без настроек